# When i minimize android app and re open webview disappears - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

So this is the app home screen.

[image]

When i go to home and re open app clicking the icon.

this shows up.

[image]

Here is more information of android studio, if you need anything else please tell me.

[image]

Comment: i see that you are testing on an emulator. try on a real device

Comment: same thing happens, app running on background state when re open clicking the icon , that happens.

Comment: did you put a code in onResume method ??

Comment: mCurrentWebView.doOnResume();
super.onResume();

Comment: at first you must put super.onResume(); above. secondly what do you mean by this instruction mCurrentWebView.doOnResume();??